# How to disable multiple column sorting on a wpf DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I need to disable multiple column sorting on a DataGrid. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you show us some code on what you have so far?

Comment: @NewAmbition: Sure, I have a DataGrid and a custom sorter, but I'm not sure if that would help you in anyway ...

Comment: Well, it would be easier to provide you with an answer within what you are currently coding if we knew what your code was.

Comment: @NewAmbition: I just need to know if the default multi column sort behaviour of the WPF DataGrid control can be disabled. As far as I see the question has nothing to do with what I've coded but on the .Net Framework capabilities.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples

Comment: @Nitesh: I want to sort but just by one column each time.

Comment: @Kyle: I don't see anything related with multi column in the article. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Nitesh: wrong. The user can sort the remaining columns, what the user should not be able to do is to sort pressing the shift key so both columns are sorted together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success by  subscribing to the DataGrid_Sorting event and setting the args' Handled property to true:

```
private void ResultsDataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. I'll do it using a behavior probably

Answer (score 0):

you can create a behavior and handle the sort be your self.
the following is not tested :)

```
public class DataGridICollectionViewSortMerkerBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Sorting += AssociatedObjectSorting;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.Sorting -= AssociatedObjectSorting;
    }

    void AssociatedObjectSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as ICollectionView;
        var propertyname = e.Column.SortMemberPath;

        e.Column.SortDirection = this.GetSortArrowForColumn(e.Column);

        if (view == null)
            return;

        view.SortDescriptions.Clear();            
        var sort = new SortDescription(propertyname, (ListSortDirection)e.Column.SortDirection);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(sort);


        e.Handled = true;
    }


    private ListSortDirection GetSortArrowForColumn(DataGridColumn col)
    {
        if (col.SortDirection == null)
        {
           return ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        else
        {
            return col.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? ListSortDirection.Descending : ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        }
    }
   }
```

xaml

```
 <DataGrid ...>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Kadia:DataGridICollectionViewSortMerkerBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: mhh even more easy should be to disable the Shift modifier in PreviewMouseDown...

Comment: how would you check the status of the Shift key or modify it?

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia you can check for `(System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) != ModifierKeys.None` and choose to ignore it, but AFAIK you cannot modify it